# My browser based app crashing chrome tab, my extension crashing chrome browser? How?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've written a browser based app that is meant to run indefinitely.  Sadly it is pretty much guaranteed to crash its Chrome tab after some number of hours (~2-6 hours).

There could be memory leaks in my code, or some library I'm using, or it could be a Chrome bug related to some newer Chrome features like WebRTC that I'm using.  It's a complicated app and my initial attempts to find leaks failed.

**Tried Auto Reloading the Page to Free Memory and Avoid Crash**

I tried to work around the issue by forcing a browser reload every 2 hours (later reduced to 1) thinking this should free any leaked memory and avoid the issue; the app is stateful so reloading isn't a real problem.

Reloading didn't solve the issue, the tab would still crash, but now it seemed like it was guaranteed to crash more in the 6-36 hour range.

**Tried Using a Chrome Extension to Reload Crashed Tabs**

I was going to launch a Chrome Extension anyway to add better integration between the site and Chrome so I added some code to the new extension to look for and reload my tab if it was found to be loaded but crashed.  I thought that worked but now with 24 - 48 hours the entire Google Browser crashes with its "Whoa! Google has crashed message."

And moving from the bizarre to the absurd I just created a little Windows app (AHK script) to look for the crashed Chrome message and restart Chrome.  Clearly I've got only one step left, to build a brand new OS to monitor the monitoring app and restart the OS if the monitoring app fails...

But seriously...  What am I not understanding about Chrome?  How is this happening?  I should stress that the little extension I wrote does almost nothing.  I cannot conceive of how it could bring down the browser.  It does nothing more than watch for my crashed tab and has a content script that lets me auto register the user account with the extension during signup or login.  I don't see anything it does that maintains any state or cache information or anything that could use up memory or cause some other problem.

Because the crashes are so infrequent I'm having a hell of a time figuring out what's going on.

I'm sorry, I know this question is vague, I'm just desperate for any insights anyone might have.  I can't find much about similar problems.

Thanks!

(I'm unable to share the site or code as the site isn't officially launched.  Given the nature of this problem I don't think that should be a problem.)

Comment: What is it about your extension that requires it to run indefinitely?  Could it be as simple as changing a background page to an event page?  Is your extension little enough that you'd be able to post it?

Comment: The background page just creates a timer event (and defines what to do when it goes off) and it causes actions in response to messages from the content script (which ONLY occur if you were on login/signup pages, which are not the pages where I see the crashes).  I should be able to clean up the background extension script and post it.  I'll go do that now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're looking for insights..

### Do you have Chrome Dev Tools (console and the like) open?

If yes, they will continuously consume resources logging network requests etc.

This may be the cause of the leaks/crashes. I've run into it once with my chrome extension. Don't let them be constantly open unless absolutely necessary.

### Try to diagnose the crash.

- Start with chrome://crashes page
- If that doesn't help, try looking for crash logs in your Chrome
  profile folder.
- If that still doesn't help, try running Chrome with [logging
  enabled](http://www.chromium.org/for-testers/enable-logging).

### Try a different (newer) version

If you're on Windows or OS X, try installing Google Chrome Canary (which is close to bleeding edge build) and see if the issue persists.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  The crashes usually occur with dev tools closed, though I have seen dev tools crash if I left it open way too long.  I submitted my crash bug, but could find no record of the crash log.  I just found an empty crash log folder, which seems odd.  Maybe the file is removed once submitted?  I'll try adding the logging switch you mention.

Comment: @QuinxyvonBesiex I added a new tip

Comment: I will try Canary (I use it on one machine but not on that one).  Just as a follow-up, my crash log was reported and I got a notice from someone in the Chromium team that the problem seems to be in the VideoDecodeAccelerator code, which seems to suggest my code isn't directly at fault.

Comment: @QuinxyvonBesiex Good to hear you got a response from Chrome team. I suggestend Canary, because it installs side by side with your normal Chrome and you can have both.

Comment: I accepted this as the answer because it is a great list of steps to take.  Thanks again!